# Wicket LoadableDetachableModel update problem

Tags: java, wicket

I have 3 LoadableDetachableModels. In their load method I am calling global variable (of the same class). In two cases, models are working just fine (method testModel1(); and testModel3();).

BUT! In testModel2(); is remaining value from first calling this Page.

I need explanation how is that even possible.

At first, I thought that ResourceReference can not be changed after init. However method testModel3() proved me otherwise. (this method is working correctly).

link on pastebin.com:
http://pastebin.com/jiFVWMMW

ouput:

Constructing object
in testModel1 value = 25.26.609
in testModel2 value = 25.26.609
in testModel2 value = 25.26.609
in testModel3 value = 25.26.671
in testModel3 value = 25.26.671
Constructing object
in testModel1 value = 25.31.625
in testModel2 value = 25.26.609
in testModel2 value = 25.26.609
in testModel3 value = 25.31.640
in testModel3 value = 25.31.640
Constructing object
in testModel1 value = 25.32.125
in testModel2 value = 25.26.609
in testModel2 value = 25.26.609
in testModel3 value = 25.32.140
in testModel3 value = 25.32.140

code:

```
package app.web;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.wicket.Resource;
import org.apache.wicket.ResourceReference;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.resources.StyleSheetReference;
import org.apache.wicket.model.LoadableDetachableModel;
import org.apache.wicket.util.resource.IResourceStream;
import org.apache.wicket.util.resource.StringResourceStream;
import org.apache.wicket.util.time.Time;
import org.wicketstuff.annotation.mount.MountPath;

/**
 * HomePage
 */
@MountPath(path = "home")
public final class HomePage extends WebPage {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "mm.ss.SS";
    transient private final Map cssMap;

    public HomePage() {
        System.out.println("Constructing object");
        cssMap = new HashMap();
        cssMap.put("time", Time.now().toString(DATE_FORMAT));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeRender() {
        testModel1();
        testModel2();
        testModel3();
        super.onBeforeRender();
    }

    /**
     * working just fine
     */
    private void testModel1() {
        add(new Label("message1", new LoadableDetachableModel() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected String load() {
                System.out.println("in testModel1 value = " + ((String) cssMap.get("time")));
                return ((String) cssMap.get("time"));
            }
        }));
    }

    /**
     * DOES NOT UPDATE!!!! (load is being called, but cssMap has original value. WTF?!
     */
    private void testModel2() {
        add(new StyleSheetReference("cssReference", new ResourceReference("testcss.css") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected Resource newResource() {
                return new Resource() {

                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    @Override
                    public IResourceStream getResourceStream() {
                        LoadableDetachableModel LDM = new LoadableDetachableModel() {

                            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                            @Override
                            protected String load() {
                                System.out.println("in testModel2 value = " + ((String) cssMap.get("time")));
                                return ((String) cssMap.get("time"));
                            }
                        };

                        return new StringResourceStream(LDM.getObject());
                    }
                };
            }
        }));
    }

    /**
     * work just fine - StyleSheet is changing...
     */
    private void testModel3() {
        add(new StyleSheetReference("cssReference2", new ResourceReference("testcss2.css") {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected Resource newResource() {
                return new Resource() {

                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    @Override
                    public IResourceStream getResourceStream() {
                        LoadableDetachableModel LDM = new LoadableDetachableModel() {

                            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                            @Override
                            protected String load() {
                                System.out.println("in testModel3 value = " + Time.now().toString(DATE_FORMAT));
                                return Time.now().toString(DATE_FORMAT);
                            }
                        };

                        return new StringResourceStream(LDM.getObject());
                    }
                };
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

html markup:

```
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/dtds.data/wicket-xhtml1.4-strict.dtd" >


        <link wicket:id="cssReference"/>
        <link wicket:id="cssReference2"/>


    <body>

message1 will be here
            </body>
</html>
```

testcss.css:
${time}

testcss2.css:
${time}

Comment: Why do you initialize the LDMs in onBeforeRender()? And why is the cssMap (which apears to be your backing for the LDM2) transient?

Comment: you do not need to publish `delete delete` there's a link to delete your question. use that.

Answer (score 1):

```
LoadableDetachableModel LDM = new LoadableDetachableModel()
```

This model is never detached, nor is it bound to a component. Component-bound models get detached automatically when the components are detached, this Model is never detached and hence the value always remains the same.

It should work if you restructure your class like this:

```
// model should be a field, so detachModels() can see it
private IModel<String> LDM = new LoadableDetachableModel<String>() {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected String load() {
        System.out.println("in testModel3 value = " + Time.now().toString(DATE_FORMAT));
        return Time.now().toString(DATE_FORMAT);
    }
};

public void detachModels() {
    super.detachModels();
    // detach the model
    LDM.detach();
}

private void testModel3() {
    add(new StyleSheetReference("cssReference2", new ResourceReference("testcss2.css") {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected Resource newResource() {
            return new Resource() {


                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public IResourceStream getResourceStream() {
                    return new StringResourceStream(LDM.getObject());
                }
            };
        }
    }));
}
```